# Need help to incoprate slide-in/out effect HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some trouble with some java script code in adding in a slide-in/slide-out effect for a slideshow. Right now, I have the timer working to change pictures every 2 sec. I have the basics of the slide-in and out in CSS just need some help implementing the java script code such that when the picture displays, it slides in and when changing pictures, the current picture slides out. Here is a link to the code pen for my code:

```js
            function plusSlides(n) {
                showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function currentSlide(n) {
                showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }

            function showSlides(n) {
                var i;
                var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                if(n > slides.length) {
                    slideIndex = 1
                }
                if(n < 1) {
                    slideIndex = slides.length
                }
                for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                        slides[i].style.display = "none";
                }

                slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            }


var index = 1;
function runSlideShow()
{
  index++;
  if(index > 5)
    index = 1
  currentSlide(index);
  setTimeout(runSlideShow, 2000)
}

setTimeout(runSlideShow, 2000)
```

```css
* {
                box-sizing: border-box
            }
            body {
                font-family: nunito sans;
                margin: 0
            }
            .mySlides {
                display: none;
            }
            center > img {
                vertical-align: middle;
                height: 75vh;
                width: auto !important;
            }
            .slideshow-container {
                max-width: 1250px;
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
            }
            /* Next & previous buttons */
            .prev,
            .next {
                cursor: pointer;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width: auto;
                padding: 16px;
                margin-top: -22px;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 18px;
                transition: 0.6s ease;
                border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
                user-select: none;
            }
            /* Position the "next button" to the right */
            .next {
                right: 0;
                border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
            }
            /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
            .prev:hover,
            .next:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            }
            /* Caption text */
            .text {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-size: 22px;
                position: absolute;
                margin: 5px 0px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
            .numbertext {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 12px;
                padding: 8px 12px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
            }

            /* Fading animation */
            .slide-in {
                -webkit-animation-name: slide-in-right;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
                animation-name: slide-in-right;
                animation-duration: 1.5s;
            }

            .slide-out {
                -webkit-animation-name: slide-out-left;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
                animation-name: slide-out-left;
                animation-duration: 1.5s;
            }

            @keyframes slide-in {
                100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
                100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
            }

            @keyframes slide-out {
                0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
                100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
                0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
                100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
            }


            /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
                .prev,
                .next,
                .text {
                    font-size: 11px
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container" width="100%">
<div class="mySlides slide-in" style="display: block;">
<center>
<div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
<img src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/theave1896.16.jpeg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">HR Koopman postcard of 112th and Michigan, facing north, in 1896.</div>
</center>
</div>
<div class="mySlides slide-in" style="display: none;">
<center>
<div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
<img src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/theave1900.34-1.jpeg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">HR Koopman photograph of workmen digging sewer system on 111th and Michigan in 1900.</div>
</center>
</div>
<div class="mySlides slide-in" style="display: none;">
<center>
<div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
<img src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/theave1903.13.jpeg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">111th and Michigan in 1903 taken by HR Koopman.</div>
</center>
</div>
<div class="mySlides slide-in" style="display: none;">
<center>
<div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
<img src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/theave1904.18.jpeg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">HR Koopman postcard showing a busy section of South Michigan Avenue on 113th street in 1904.</div>
</center>
</div>
<div class="mySlides slide-in" style="display: none;">
<center>
<div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
<img src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/theave1909.12.jpeg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Roseland celebrates its 60th anniversary with a huge parade on July 5th, 1909.</div>
</center>
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade" style="display: none;">
<center>
<div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
<img src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/theave1910.24.jpeg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">HR Koopman photograph of 115th and Michigan in 1910 showing horse and buggies, a streetcar, and bicycles.</div>
</center>
</div>
</div>
<br>

</div></div>
</div></div>
```

https://codepen.io/philm001/pen/abYqGew

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove the animations dynamically toggling classes.

When showing a new slide:

```
slideToShow.classList.add(“slide-in”)
slideToShow.classList.remove(“slide-out”)
slideToHide.classList.remove(“slide-in”)
slideToHide.classList.add(“slide-out”)
```

*I wrote this answer on mobile so beware of the quotation marks I used. They are not the correct character.*

Comment: Hello thank you for your comment. The thing is, this needs to animate the slide out when changing pics. Not sure how to insert your pic on a slide out and make it disappear. Also tried the code and it did not for me (slide in)